# Does the classical equation for work apply to upward acceleration to oppose gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, work

So, the classical work equation is force * distance.  And so holding an apple in your hand so that it doesn't move with respect to the earth would mean you are doing no work, and the apple is not gaining energy, either potential or kinetic.

However, in GR, an object held so that it resists gravity is experiencing acceleration in space-time.  Does the classical work equation apply in this context?  Is work entirely relative such that it is meaningless to consider it without a chosen frame of reference, such as with respect to earth (and the surface of earth is experiencing similar acceleration)?  What about the gravitational gradient that means the apple experiences ever so slightly less acceleration then the surface of earth below it?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the classical work equation apply in this context?

The standard equation applies at low velocities. At relativistic velocities it will be easier to use the four-force.

> Is work entirely relative such that it is meaningless to consider it without a chosen frame of reference, such as with respect to earth (and the surface of earth is experiencing similar acceleration)?

Yes, work is entirely relative and must be specified with respect to some reference frame. This is not often emphasized in introductory physics classes, but it holds in Newtonian mechanics. This is **not** a feature specific to relativity.

A good example of this is a gravitational slingshot. If you calculate the work done on the satellite in the planet's reference frame, you get 0. But in the reference frame of the sun you can get a lot of work done on the satellite, analyzed purely with Newtonian physics. This is indeed the purpose of a gravitational slingshot maneuver.

Often in introductory course this frame dependence for work is hidden by the fact that the reference frame that is used for a given problem is implicitly understood by context. but the fact remains that it is inherently a frame-dependent quantity.

> What about the gravitational gradient that means the apple experiences ever so slightly less acceleration then the surface of earth below it?

The gravitational gradient is important to calculating the work in non-relativistic physics also. So, while all of the concerns you bring up are valid, they are not limited to relativity.

Comment: While that is a helpful answer, I'm left unclear if I am doing work (from the earth's reference frame) on the apple by holding it from falling.

Comment: @HardlyCurious as you say, in this frame the displacement is 0 so the work is 0.

Comment: The displacement is zero in 3 dimensional space, but to my understanding the displacement wouldn't be zero in 4 dimensional spacetime.